# How can I concurrently modify a set through indirect actions in java?

Tags: java, list, iteration

I've read a bit about list concurrency and i'm facing this issue:

I have a list that i need to go through. Each time I process an element from this list some list-changing effects can happen (among many other things).

- The current element can be discarded (and replaced by null in the list to mark an empty spot)
- An other random element from the list can be discarded (and replaced by null)
- An element can be added to the end of the list (which can be an element that was removed previously by an other action)

These list-changing effect do not directly happen during the loop. They can be triggered by an action on one of the element. All this is done synchronously.

Here's a simplified version of what it currently looks like.

```java
class Container {
    List<Element> elements;

    // It starts here
    public void process() {
        for (Element el: this.elements)) {
            el.doSomething(this);
        }
    }

    public void removeElement(Element el) {
        this.elements.remove(el);
    }
}

class Element {
    public void doSomething(Container c) {
        this.doThis();
        this.getAction().applyTo(c);
    }
}

class MyAction implements Action<Container> {
    void applyTo(Container c) {
        for (Element el: this.getElements())) { // getElements does an immutable copy of this.elements
            el.doThat();
            if(el.shouldBeRemoved()) {
                c.removeElement(el);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The best solution I've come to find yet is the following:

```java
public void process() {
    for (Element el: this.getElements()) {// getElements does an immutable copy of this.elements
        if (!this.elements.contains(el)) continue;
        el.doSomething(this);
    }
}
```

It does not account for the fact an element could be added to the list but I currently do not need to process elements that have been added during this call of `process()`.

So this works but it leads to a lot of list copying.

I've thought about `CopyOnWriteArrayList` but it still copies the list except it may copy it numerous time during the loop which is less performant.
I've put aside the `ListIterator` as i would need to have a reference to the original list iterator.

The last option I thought of would be to flag elements instead of replacing them by null so that they are ignored by any action but that would force me to add a lot of conditions like: `el.isFlagOk()`. Plus it would force me to duplicate elements in case a removed element needs to be added back to the end (instead of just resetting it as I currently do).
FYI the list has a functional maximum size of 10.

Is there a list-type structure that would support this kind of intertwined behavior ?

Comment: What you could try, is to rewrite the process using standard arrays and manual standard loops. At least then you have direct control of the looping logic and you wont have concurrency issues. It might also reveal some logical issues with your code flow.

Answer (score 0):

So what you need is that the elements can adjust the list potentially while the list is being iterated upon?

For this possibly you could look at having 2 lists in the container. One of which can be acquired for iterating and one that is edited. The edited would then need to replace the iterated list when the iteration is complete.

So:

```
class Container {
    List<Element> elements;
    List<Element> itr;

    ...
    public void process() {
        for (Element el: itr) {

            el.doSomething(this);
        }
        swap();

    }

    private void swap(){
         itr = elements;
         elements = getElements();//assuming getElements does an immutable copy of this.itr
    }

}
```

Comment: It sounds as though the changes can affect the decision making process later in the same iteration. Something you wouldn't be able to do with a second collection, because the list being iterated over won't be able to adjust for changes in the other list.

Comment: Yes i think is see that now maybe not 2 lists then :/